# Combine set of conditions in data.table to extract value using binary search

Tags: r, replace, data.table

Since my terrible execution and interpretation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669399/extract-value-from-one-dataframe-and-place-into-other-based-on-a-set-of-conditio) I'll start over and will try to formulate the question as short and general possible.

I have two dataframes (see the examples below). Each dataset contains the same number of columns.

```
tc <- textConnection('
ID  Track1  Track2  Track3  Track4  Time    Loc
4   15      ""      ""      50      40      1   
5   17      115     109     55      50      1   
6   17      115     109     55      60      1   
7   13      195     150     60      70      1
8   13      195     150     60      80      1
9   ""      ""      181     70      90      2 #From this row, example data added
10  ""      ""      182     70      92      2
11  429     31      ""      80      95      3
12  480     31      12      80      96      3 
13  118     ""      ""      90      100     4
14  120     16      213     90      101     4   
')

MATCHINGS <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)

tc <- textConnection('
ID  Track1  Track2  Track3  Track4  Time    Loc
""  15      ""      ""      50      40      1   
""  17      ""     109      55      50      1
""  17      432    109      55      65      1   
""  17      115     109     55      59      1       
""  13      195     150     60      68      1
""  13      195     150     60      62      1
""  10      5       1       10      61      3
""  13      195     150     60      72      1
""  40      ""      181     70      82      2 #From this row, example data added
""  ""      ""      182     70      85      2
""  429     ""      ""      80      90      3
""  ""      31      12      80      92      3
""  ""      ""      ""      90      95      4
""  118     16      213     90      96      4
')

INVOLVED <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)
```

The goal is to place the least recent ID from `MATCHINGS` into `INVOLVED` by matching on `Track1` to `Track4` and `Loc`. An extra condition is that the `Time` of the matching `INVOLVED` entry may not be higher than the `Time` of the entry in `MATCHING`. Furthermore a match on `Track1` is most preferred, a match on `Track4` is least preferred. However only `Track4` is always available (all other `Track`-columns can be empty). Thus the expected results are:

```
ID Track1 Track2 Track3 Track4 Time Loc
4     15     ""     ""     50   40   1
5     17     ""    109     55   50   1
""    17    432    109     55   65   1
6     17    115    109     55   59   1
7     13    195    150     60   68   1
7     13    195    150     60   62   1
""    10      5      1     10   61   3
8     13    195    150     60   72   1
9     40     ""    181     70   82   2 #From this row, example data added
10    ""     ""    182     70   85   2
11    429    ""     ""     80   90   3
12    ""     31     12     80   92   3
13    ""     ""     ""     90   95   4 
13    118    16    213     90   96   4
```

I tried to this with the `data.table` package, but fail in doing this efficient. Is it possible to get rid of the vector scans and efficiently go through the data without looping?

```
dat <- data.table(MATCHINGS)
for(i in 1:nrow(INVOLVED)){
    row <- INVOLVED[i,]
    match <- dat[Time>=row$Time][Loc==row$Loc][Track4==row$Track4][Track4!=""][order(Time)][1]
    if(!is.na(match$ID)){ INVOLVED$ID[i]<-match$ID }
    match <- dat[Time>=row$Time][Loc==row$Loc][Track3==row$Track3][Track3!=""][order(Time)][1]
    if(!is.na(match$ID)){ INVOLVED$ID[i]<-match$ID }
    match <- dat[Time>=row$Time][Loc==row$Loc][Track2==row$Track2][Track2!=""][order(Time)][1]
    if(!is.na(match$ID)){ INVOLVED$ID[i]<-match$ID }
    match <- dat[Time>=row$Time][Loc==row$Loc][Track1==row$Track1][Track1!=""][order(Time)][1]
    if(!is.na(match$ID)){ INVOLVED$ID[i]<-match$ID }
}
```

**update**

Updated the example data showing the need for `Track 1 to 3`. As shown `Track1` is most important and `Track4` least important. Even if `Track1 to 3` match to `MATCHINGS x` and `Track4` matches to `MATCHINGS y`, the `ID` of `y` should be assigned to that `INVOLVED row`. So: `Track3` match overrides `Track4` match, `Track2` match overrides `Track3` match, `Track1` match overrides `Track2` match.

Comment: Is the data sorted somehow or it could come in any order regarding the matching columns? Based on the example data it seems that you should be able to create a surrogate key that would summarize the Track1-Track4 & Loc in a single unique value. Is this the case?

Comment: You mean give combinations of Track 1 to 4 and Loc an ID based on their values? So you could match these new surrogate IDs? Since multiple forms of tracking can be missing, I don't think that you would be able to match using a surrogate key. For instance if the entry from MATCHING contains 3 types of tracking and the corresponding entry from INVOLVED contains only two, you would get different keys, even though it should match.

Comment: I confess that I have difficulty to understand your code... So this means that as long as Loc matches and ANY of the values between Track1-Track4 is then there is a match, right? And, on top of that, you give preference to an matched id coming from Track1 than Track4 based on the order of their match statement in the code right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Track1 is most preferred, track4 least preferred. Track 4 is always there and all other fields can be missing. I also put that in the question.

Comment: You are not thinking in a data.table way. Reread the vignettes and examples - think how this can be done with merging and `by` etc. At the moment your code is not using any of the `data.table` efficiency!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With roll argument able to also roll next observation backward along with the new (`v1.9.6+`) `on=` argument, we can do this much more straightforward:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(MATCHINGS)
setDT(INVOLVED)
INVOLVED[ , ID := MATCHINGS[INVOLVED, ID, roll=-Inf, 
                    mult="first", on=c("Loc", "Track4", "Time")]]]
```

That's it.

---

Here's a `data.table`-ish start. This only uses Track 4 (not 1 to 3) but it still appears to produce the requested output.

```
M = as.data.table(MATCHINGS)
I = as.data.table(INVOLVED)
M[,Time:=-Time]
I[,Time:=-Time]
setkey(M,Loc,Track4,Time)
I[,ID:={i=list(Loc,Track4,Time);M[i,ID,roll=TRUE,mult="first"]}][,Time:=-Time]

    ID Track1 Track2 Track3 Track4 Time Loc
 1:  1     NA    105     NA     35    1   1
 2:  1     NA     NA     NA     35    2   1
 3:  1     26    105     NA     35    3   1
 4:  2     NA     NA     NA     40   20   1
 5:  2    134      1      6     40   20   1
 6:  3     13    109     NA     45   30   1
 7:  4     15     NA     NA     50   40   1
 8:  5     17     NA    109     55   50   1
 9: NA     17    432    109     55   65   1
10:  6     17    115    109     55   59   1
11:  7     13    195    150     60   68   1
12:  7     13    195    150     60   62   1
13: NA     10      5      1     10   61   3
14:  8     13    195    150     60   72   1
```

Interesting question!  If this seems ok, please change the example data to need tracks 1 to 3. Or perhaps you can take it from here.

Comment: I've never thought of using `{` within `:=` -- that is pure scoping genius!

Comment: Brilliant! This is so very, very fast! Indeed track1 to 3 are not needed in the example data. I will try to come up with an example where 1,2,3 are needed later. 

One question: why do you use the `Time:=-Time` calls. Is that for `mult="first"` to get the oldest instead of newest record?

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden Yes, sort of. Because you needed _first-after_ rather the _last-before_, is perhaps the way I'd word it. `roll=TRUE` does _last-on-or-before_. Changing signs changes that to _first-on-or-after_. But that trick only works for `integer` and `double`, not `character`.

Comment: I've updated the example to include `Track1 to 3` and thus to take into account the importance of the 4 types of tracking. I've deleted the entries belonging to the first 3 orders to save some space.

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden Good. What have you tried? Have you understood the proposed approach and can you extend it?

Comment: @MatthewDowle I'm currently looking in to understanding and the possibility of extending your solution. Will report back

Comment: @MatthewDowle Long time since a reply (very busy times!), but I do not know how to integrate all types of tracking in 1 function. The way I can manage is is to first run for track 4, than for track 3, 2 etc. (subsetting the dataset so that it does not include records where the particular form if tracking is NA). Is it possible to include it in one function?

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden Yes, almost anything can be wrapped up in one function. The way you've described sounds ok to me.

Comment: @MatthewDowle wrapped the above solution in a function, which works perfectly. There is one rule that I cannot get incorporated in I[,ID:={i=list(Loc,Track4,Time);M[i,ID,roll=TRUE,mult="first"]}][,Time:=-Time] - call and that is that Time of the INVOLVED entry may not be more than 2592000 seconds (30 days) less than the MATCHINGS entry that matches. Thus the involved entry may not be older than 2592000 seconds compared to the MATCHINGS time. Is it easy to incorporate this constraint. I cannot see where to place this condition.

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden That sounds like an excellent new question. There is a feature request related to that, but it should be possible already.

Comment: @MatthewDowle FYI the followup question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501305/incorporate-a-time-constraint-by-matching-with-data-table

Comment: @MaxvanderHeijden I can't think of a better solution than Arun's. Other than implementing the feature request, which I'm working on in free time. Nearly ready ...