# Incorporate a time constraint by matching with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This question is a follow-up to a previous question: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723182/combine-set-of-conditions-in-data-table-to-extract-value-using-binary-search/)

In this question two data.frames are provided, since this question focuses on a more specific part, the example data is reduced.

```
tc <- textConnection('
ID  Track4  Time    Loc
4   50      40      1   
5   55      50      1   
6   55      60      1   

')

MATCHINGS <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)

tc <- textConnection('
ID  Track4  Time    Loc
""  50      40      1   
""  55      10      1
""  55      40      1   
""  55      59      1     ')  

INVOLVED <- read.table(tc, header=TRUE)
```

In the previous question a solution was found to this problem: The goal is to place the least recent `ID` from `MATCHINGS` into `INVOLVED` by matching on `Track1` and `Loc`. An extra condition is that the `Time` of the matching `INVOLVED` entry may not be higher than the `Time` of the entry in `MATCHING`. This was achieved with the current approach (see below)

A new constraint is that: the `Time` of the `INVOLVED` entry may not be more than 30 seconds (`Time` column is in seconds) lower than the `MATCHINGS` entry. Right now the following output is achieved:

```
ID Track4 Time Loc
4     50   40   1
5     55   10   1
5     55   40   1
6     55   59   1
```

The expected results are however:

```
ID Track4 Time Loc
4     50   40   1
""    55   10   1
5     55   40   1
6     55   59   1
```

Since the Time of the `INVOLVED` entry is more than 30 seconds lower than the `MATCHINGS` entry that matches on `Track4` and `Loc`. I do not see how to incorporate this in my current solution. According to Matthew Dowle a feature request in de data.table package is related to this issue, but it should already be possible to incoporate. Does anyone know how?

The current approach (Without taking the time constraint into account)

```
M = as.data.table(MATCHINGS)
I = as.data.table(INVOLVED)
M[,Time:=-Time]
I[,Time:=-Time]
setkey(M,Loc,Track4,Time)
I[,ID:={i=list(Loc,Track4,Time);M[i,ID,roll=TRUE,mult="first"]}][,Time:=-Time]
```

Comment: No,  it may not be **more** than 30 seconds. So the difference between the `Time` of the `INVOLVED` and `MATCHINGS` entry may not be more than 30 seconds (so 30 seconds or less) + `Time` of the `INVOLVED` entry may not be higher than `Time` of the `MATCHINGS` entry. This last bit is already incorporated.

Comment: Updated answer to highlight finite rollbacks/forwards feature (implemented long ago) along with `on=` argument (implemented in v1.9.6). Please review and accept if it solves your issue, so that the Q remains answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** `roll` argument in *data.table* accepts finite *roll backs* and *roll forwards* since A LONG TIME. Just updating this post so that we can close [#615](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/615).

```
# dt1 = MATCHES, dt2 = INVOLVED
# make sure dt2 doesn't have `ID` column, or if it has, it is of integer type
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
dt2[dt1, ID := i.ID, on=c("Track4", "Time"), roll=30]
#    Track4 Time Loc ID
# 1:     50   40   1  4
# 2:     55   10   1 NA
# 3:     55   40   1  5
# 4:     55   59   1  6
```

Also using the `on=` argument implemented in `v1.9.6`.

See history for the older answer if necessary.

Comment: +1 Great solution. The best place for it is deep in C really isn't it. Since this is coming up quite a bit in different threads, I've been working on it in free time. `roll` can take +30 (roll forwards) and -30 (roll backwards), `rolltolast` TRUE/FALSE as before and new `rollfirstback` also TRUE/FALSE.  The current roll=TRUE corresponds to roll=+Inf, but TRUE will still be acceptable for backwards compatibility.